# Problems with one hot encoding

Tags: python, deep-learning, one-hot-encoding

I am using a fairly simple piece of code to `one hot encode` my categorical variables in the data. The code is as follows:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
onehot_encoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)    
onehot_encoded_quartile = onehot_encoder.fit_transform(df.quartile.reshape(-1, 1))
onehot_encoded_mt = onehot_encoder.fit_transform(df.modality_type.reshape(-1, 1))
onehot_encoded_quartile.shape, onehot_encoded_mt.shape
((1, 2173651), (2173651, 31))
```

Number of records in `df`: 2173651

I would have expected both the variables to have similar shape in the first dimension. The correct shape should have been `(2173651,X)`, where X would be the number of categories in each variable/feature.

Number of categories in `df.modality_type`: 31

Number of categories in `df.quartile`: 3

Here's the content of both the variables:

```
df.modality_type.head(),df.quartile.head()

(8     0
 11    0
 15    0
 16    0
 21    1
 Name: modality_type, dtype: int64, 8     0
 11    1
 15    1
 16    2
 21    2
 Name: quartile, dtype: category
 Categories (3, int64): [1 < 2 < 0])
```

Why do I have different shapes here? How can I get the correct shapes to be `(2173651,X)`?

Comment: What is `onehot_encoder`?

Comment: It's now included in the code.

Comment: can you please print what is in df.quartile and df.modality_type?

Comment: @lejlot Updated the question.

Comment: it looks like some odd handling of type "category", convert quartile to integer prior to your code and you should be fine